# Python - Monkey Patching weird bug

Tags: python, unit-testing, monkeypatching

My Fake Mock Class looks like following:

```
class FakeResponse:
    method = None               # 
    url = None                  # static class variables

    def __init__(self, method, url, data):#, response):
        self.status_code = 200       # always return 200 OK
        FakeResponse.method = method # 
        FakeResponse.url = url       #

    @staticmethod
    def check(method, url, values):
       """ checks method and URL.      
       """
       print "url fake: ", FakeResponse.url
       assert FakeResponse.method == method
       assert FakeResponse.url == url
```

I have another decorator which is applicable over all the test cases:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def no_requests(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('haas.cli.do_put',
                    lambda url,data: FakeResponse('PUT', url, data))
    monkeypatch.setattr("haas.cli.do_post",
                    lambda url,data: FakeResponse('POST', url, data))
    monkeypatch.setattr("haas.cli.do_delete",
                    lambda url: FakeResponse('DELETE', url, None))
```

I am using Py.test to test the code.

Some example test cases are:

```
class Test:
    #test case passes
    def test_node_connect_network(self):
       cli.node_connect_network('node-99','eth0','hammernet')
       FakeResponse.check('POST','http://abc:5000/node/node-99/nic/eth0/connect_network',
                        {'network':'hammernet'})

    # test case fails
    def test_port_register(self):
        cli.port_register('1') # This make a indirect REST call to the original API
        FakeResponse.check('PUT','http://abc:5000/port/1', None)

    # test case fails
    def test_port_delete(self):
        cli.port_delete('port', 1)
        FakeResponse.check('DELETE','http://abc:5000/port/1', None)
```

A sample error message which I get:

```
    method = 'PUT', url = 'http://abc:5000/port/1', values = None

    @staticmethod
    def check(method, url, values):
        """ checks method and URL.
           'values': if None, verifies no data was sent.
           if list of (name,value) pairs, verifies that each pair is in 'values'
        """
        print "url fake: ", FakeResponse.url
>       assert FakeResponse.method == method
E       assert 'POST' == 'PUT'
E         - POST
E         + PUT
haas/tests/unit/cli_v1.py:54: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------
port_register <port>
Register a <port> on a switch
url fake:  http://abc:5000/node/node-99/nic/eth0/connect_network
--------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call -------------------------------------
Wrong number of arguements.  Usage:
```

Whereas if I call the second test case in the following way considering the
check function takes "self" argument and @staticmethod is not used then the test case works:

```
def test_port_register(self):
    cli.port_register('1')
    fp = FakeResponse('PUT','http://abc:5000/port/1', None) #Create a FakeResponse class instance
    fp.check('PUT','http://abc:5000/port/1', None) # Just call the check function with the same                                                          
                                                     arguments
```

Questions:

- Are there any side effects of using monkey patching and @staticmethod
- How is the url defined for a previous test function being used in the next function call.
- Should'nt there be a scoping of argument to disallow the above unwanted behavior.
- Is there a better way to monkey patch.

Sorry for the long post, I have been trying to resolve this for a week and wanted some perspective
 of other programmers.

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting to happen here. You're explicitly using class attributes, so I don't see why you're surprised when they persist between instances: that's the whole point of class attributes.

Comment: Is there a better way to accomplish the fake test. Internally the attributes of FakeResponse class are used in another module to do some computation.

Comment: Try to debug `cli.port_register('1')` and check it not call a `POST` request after the `PUT`. Your code is not beautiful but it should work... but only check *last* call to `FakeResponse()`

Comment: You can try to use `mock` framework to build a mock request. I can try to fill an answer later by using `mock` framework.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was not having the right signature for one of the functions. It was resolved by changing the argument passed to the MonkeyPatch function as en empty dictionary {} instead of 'None' value which is kind of specific to my code.

The reason the I was initially hitting the issue was, as the current function's call(cli.port_register) was failing when the parameters where passed to port_register itself, so it picked up the argument values from a previous state and doing the assert with the FakeResponse call.